# On hover of li make anchor different color?

Tags: css, hover, html-lists, anchor

I looked for a solution to my problem here by making my anchor tag's width 100% but nothing seemed to work.

The desired effect is to have the entire li be an anchor tag so that on hover of the li the anchor's color changes, and the entire li is clickable

```css
.totem-container {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 200px;
  color: #222222;
  padding-top: 200px;
}

.totem-list {
  width: 200px;
}

.totem-list li {
  width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
  list-style: none;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 10px -6px #222;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 10px -6px #222;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px -6px #222;
}

.totem-list li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.totem-list a {
  color: #222222;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.totem-list a:hover {
  color: #78A025; !important
}

.totem-list i {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: #4f4f4f;
}
 
.totem-list i.social {
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1px;
  color: #007DC3;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

.totem-list i.social:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  color: #78A025;
}
```

```html
<head>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="totem-container center-block pull-right">
    <ul class="totem-list">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square social"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square social"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square social"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-square social"></i></a>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
        <a href="#">Contact Sales</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>
        <a href="#">Log In</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  </body
```

What do I need to change in order to achieve this?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. An `<a>` can't be a child of a `<ul>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CSS Flexbox**. Make your `<li>` a flex container to make it full width. For hovering you can do `:hover` on `<li>` and make your `<a>` of different color, like:

```
.totem-list li {
  display: flex;
}

.totem-list li:hover a {
  color: #78A025; !important
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.totem-container {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 200px;
  color: #222222;
  padding-top: 200px;
}

.totem-list {
  width: 200px;
}

.totem-list li {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
  list-style: none;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 10px -6px #222;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 10px -6px #222;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px -6px #222;
}

.totem-list li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.totem-list li:hover a {
  color: #78A025; !important
}

.totem-list a {
  flex: 1;
  color: #222222;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.totem-list a:hover {
  color: #78A025; !important
}

.totem-list i {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: #4f4f4f;
}
 
.totem-list i.social {
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1px;
  color: #007DC3;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

.totem-list i.social:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  color: #78A025;
}
```

```html
<head>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="totem-container center-block pull-right">
    <ul class="totem-list">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square social"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square social"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square social"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-square social"></i></a>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
        <a href="#">Contact Sales</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>
        <a href="#">Log In</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  </body
```

Hope this helps!